# java cast generic type without unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

I'm trying to understand how to use the `Function<T,R>` interface, defined in java libraries.
Why passing an instance of `DoubleIt` to `map` works, but passing a constructor reference get the compiler error below, and is there any way to do that:

[image: compiler error]

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Stream<Integer> stream = Arrays.stream(new Integer[]{2, Integer.MAX_VALUE});

        DoubleIt<Integer, Long> doubleIt = new DoubleIt<>(); 
        stream.map(doubleIt)                     // OK      instance
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        stream.map(DoubleIt<Integer, Long>::new) // error   constructor reference
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class DoubleIt<T extends Integer, R extends Long> implements Function<T, R> {

    @Override
    public R apply(T t) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final R r = (R) Long.valueOf(t.intValue() * 2L);
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems a bit overcomplicated. Why exactly is `DoubleIt` a class when you could just write `Function<Integer, Long> doubleIt = i -> i * 2L`?

Comment: I want to override the `andThen` method and figure out how to work with it. However, your example is worth it if I have only the `apply` method. Thanks.

Comment: Don’t create fake type parameters. Declare the correct type `class DoubleIt implements Function<Integer, Long> { @Override public Long apply(Integer t) { return t * 2L; } }` and you don’t need any `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one passes a `DoubleIt` instance, the other one passes a method to construct a `DoubleIt` instance, the two have very different signatures. Why would you expect them to be interchangeable?

The first can consume an `Integer` and return a `Long`, the second one can consume nothing and return a `DoubleIt`. They do very different things and therefore you cannot use one in place of the other.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I misunderstand the concept of constructor reference. You explain it very clearly.